# How can I get NSLayoutConstraint to force UIViews to be as small as possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

How can I get all these UIViews to be as small as their internal content?

This is what I am seeing

```
|-10-|[UIView    ]|-10-|[UIView    ]|-10-|[UIView    ]|-10-||-----------|
```

What I want to see?

```
|-10-|[UIView]|-10-|[UIView]|-10-|[UIView]|-10-||-----------------------|
```

I want to always push toward the left or hug content to the left.

Each of the UIViews above contain other views. So something like this. The UIViews are XIBs with backing code. The xibs and backing code are squishing left appropriately. But when I throw the XIB into the UIViews above. The UIViews above don't squish left.

[image]

The blue box is the XIB and it is hugging content correctly. But the red box and the constraints that are at the storyboard level will not hug or squish the content. I can't seem to get the NSLayoutConstraints to always hug left.

Comment: Depends on what the views contain. What do the views contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to keep the UIView's at a constant = 10 from each other, but you don't mind the leading to the superview.

```
|-10@1000-[UIView]-10@1000-[UIView]-10@1000-[UIView]->=10@250-|
```

By changing the priority on the leading, you guarantee that the distance to the right edge will vary. See how the priority is less that the hugging for the views.